# How to set image as background for a shapefile polygon using QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, shapefile, polygon, image

I would like to change the background of a polygon to an image using QGIS. Under Symbology, there is an option for Raster Fill but the .jpg image is so zoomed in you cannot see it. Is there a way to make the polygon background an image and move it around so it looks good? Any tips on file types, resolutions, or anything?

Comment: What type of image are you trying to use? I think it's meant for textured images rather than one that will fit inside a polygon like a 5x7 print... with that said, can you adjust the percentage display properties?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply change the Image width: depending on what size you want, define a value for the no. of pixels the fill image should have:

[image]

[image]